# Is every serializable schedule view serializable?

Tags: database, transactions

In DBMS Schedules of Transactions:
We know that conflict serializability is a proper subset of view serializability.
But view serializable schedules may contains all serializable schedules. Or view serializability is just a proper subset of view serializability?
Has anyone checked this?